# Using siunitx when already using the S column from cellspace

Tags: tables, siunitx, adjustbox

I want to include images in my tabularx such that they are vertically centered, so I used code from [Issue with vertical align image in table cell](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/430760/issue-with-vertical-align-image-in-table-cell)

That works fine, except that when I add the siunitx package to that example it fails with `Error:(7) Argument of \Gin@ii has an extra }.`

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[export,demo]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{cellspace} % [Edit] This provides the S column type for extra vertical space
\usepackage{siunitx} % Also provides the S column type for aligning decimal digits

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{|Sc|}
        \includegraphics[valign=c]{test} \\
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Because the MWE itself is not my original problem, this is my full problem which should vertically center images, and which is exactly the answer [I mentioned](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/430829/98850) but with the siunitx package added (I need the siunitx package):

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[export, demo]{adjustbox}    % in real document delete option "demo"
% adjustbox call "graphicx"
% "adjustbox" call "graphicx" plus add many function
% for manipulating boxes, among them here is used "valign"
\usepackage{cellspace,                  % for adding vertical space around cells' contents
tabularx}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{4pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{4pt}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}  % for vertical centering of X cell contents
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htb]
        \centering
        \setkeys{Gin}{width=11mm,height=11mm}   % with real images should be sufficient defined only image width
        %
        \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|Sc|l|>{\RaggedRight}X|} % "S" add vertical space in column "c"
            \hline
            \textbf{Menu item}  & \textbf{Caption}  & \textbf{Description} \\
            \hline
            \includegraphics[valign=c]{security_unlock.png}% "valing=c" move baseline of the image to its middle
            & Login             & Show the login screen, where
            the user should enter his
            credentials to log on to the
            system.               \\
            \hline
            \includegraphics[valign=c]{security_lock.png}%
            & Logoff            & Log off the current user. A
            prompt will be shown where
            the user has to confirm the
            log off procedure.    \\
            \hline
            \includegraphics[valign=c]{employees-gear.png}%
            & Manage            & Opens a formular where the
            user can manage the user
            groups and users.     \\
            \hline
        \end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Output:

```
main.tex:40: Argument of \Gin@ii has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.40         \end{tabularx}
                           
Runaway argument?
val\bool_if:NT \l__siunitx_table_math_bool {\scan_stop: \c_math_toggle_token \E
TC.
```

MiKTeX 4.0.1, siunitx version 26-02-2020, adjustbox 30-08-2020, all packages up to date (and also happens on an up-to-date TeX Live).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve your problem with load `cellspace` package as

```
\usepackage[column=O]{cellspace}
```

as suggested @ Ulrike Fischer in her comment, and then determine table as

```
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|Oc|l|>{\RaggedRight}X|} % "O" add vertical space in column "c"
```

However, you can insert images in table ba use of `adjustbox`, which is already loaded, capability to add margins around image by use of parameter `margin`. In this case you can remove `cellspace` stuff from document preamble:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[demo,               % in real document delete option "demo"
            export]{adjustbox}  % "adjustbox" call "graphicx" plus add many function
                                % for manipulating boxes, among them here is used "valign"
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htb]
    \centering
    \renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}  % for vertical centering of X cell contents
    \adjustboxset{width=11mm, height=11mm,valign=c, margin=0pt 3pt 0pt 3pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|c|l|>{\RaggedRight}X|} % "S" add vertical space in column "c"
    \hline
\textbf{Menu item}  & \textbf{Caption}  & \textbf{Description}  \\
    \hline
\adjustimage{}{security_unlock.png}% 
    & Login         & Show the login screen, 
                      where the user should enter his
                      credentials to log on to the system.      \\
    \hline
\adjustimage{}{security_lock.png}%
    & Logoff        & Log off the current user. A prompt will be 
                      shown where the user has to confirm the
                      log off procedure.                        \\
    \hline
\adjustimage{}{employees-gear.png}%
    & Manage        & Opens a formular where the user can manage 
                      the user groups and users.     \\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think you meant to type `Oc` instead of `=c` in that first solution. This is a great alternative, actually even better because I don't need to change the column type at all, thanks!

Comment: @PHPirate, you are right! I miss the key on keyboard :-(

Answer (score 2):

you should protect material that siunitx should not align at the decimal number in S-columns by adding braces:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[export,demo]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{|Sc|}
        {\includegraphics[valign=c]{example-image}} \\
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ah, I see now that the siunitx package also defines the `S` column type and with that overrides the behaviour I need (the extra vertical space), that's a pity.

Comment: sorry I hadn't seen the cellspace reference, use `\usepackage[column=O]{cellspace}` to get a different name for its column type.

Comment: That was my mistake, I had incorrectly left it out of the MWE. That fixes it, thanks!